# In a grid of convex polygons, what is the maximun number of adjacent neighbors a polygon could have?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, coloring

Maybe is a dumb question, but I'm working in a procedural map generation system. Each map is composed by regions. I know for sure that each polygon is convex, because I'm using a Voronoi space subdivision algorithm (or quads or hexagons as alternative). Now I need to paint each region with a color, and color has to be visually different, so, for couriosity, I'm asking if there is a way to calculate the maximun adjacent regions that a polygon could have in a grid made all with convex polygons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no maximum. One Voronoi region may have as many neighbors as you want.

[image: A sample Voronoi diagram]
(constructed with http://alexbeutel.com/webgl/voronoi.html)

Comment: But still fours colors suffice, http://experimentalmath.info/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/urbana.png

Comment: True, but that's another story.